# How to implement Video trimming on android like instagram or Whatsapp?

Tags: android, video

I need to trim the video in my android apps like Instagram or Whatsapp. I searched a lot but did not find much stuff. Is there any library for this like aviary SDK for video trimming?
At the time of trimming in Instagram or Whatsapp video is split or cut into multiple frames like given screenshot and after that user select specific frames from it for trimming video between these frames or specific time.
[image] [image]

Comment: You have to use this library [link(]http://hiteshsondhi88.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/) and for  video range you can use this widget [link](https://github.com/edmodo/range-bar) and for frame extract you can use MediaMetadataRetriever  android class .

Comment: are you know the answer then give me hint because i also need that type of funcionality.

Comment: @shailesh If you know the answer, please tell me. This is exactly what I want.

Comment: @OmidZamani Did not get me also. I have done with seek bar without video frame.

Comment: how to select  maximum of `30` range  between total duration I am using `RangeSeekBarView` for trimming video  for this example https://github.com/HemendraGangwar/VideoTrimmingLikeWhatsapp any help will be accepted

Comment: @Maroti Did you get any solution?

Comment: if it's possible to make ui like this in flutter?

Answer (score 1):

Use this Library for video trimming like whats app and insta.
[see this library](https://github.com/knowledge4life/k4l-video-trimmer)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @MilanPansuriya can you help for the example  that you provided link? I want to set maximum frame of `30s`  in selector any help will be accepted.

Comment: @SagarHudge you can set your time limit and other function like video bit rate and video resolution plz follow library documentation.

Answer (score 1):

FFmpeg can be used to extract frames from video and cut video.

For integrating FFmpeg in android we can use precompiled libraries like [ffmpeg-android](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android).

For extracting image frames from video use below command-

```
String[] complexCommand = {"-y", "-i", inputFileAbsolutePath, "-an", "-r", "1/2", "-ss", "" + startMs / 1000, "-t", "" + (endMs - startMs) / 1000, outputFileAbsolutePath()};
```

For cutting video use below command-

```
String[] complexCommand = {"-ss", "" + startMs / 1000, "-y", "-i", inputFileAbsolutePath, "-t", "" + (endMs - startMs) / 1000, "-s", "320x240", "-r", "15", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-b:v", "2097152", "-b:a", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", outputFileAbsolutePath};
```

You can use  [RangeSeekBar](https://github.com/anothem/android-range-seek-bar) to allow user to select the time range for cutting video from original video.
For complete tutorial check out below post on my blog-

https://androidlearnersite.wordpress.com/2017/03/17/ffmpeg-video-editor/

Answer (score 0):

Use this [Android-video_trimmer](https://github.com/a914-gowtham/Android-video-trimmer) android library.it is using Exoplayer2 and FFmpeg underneath.it supports android 10